Laravel 11 with Jetstream and Inertia Remove ShareInertiaData Middleware
Removing the \Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\ShareInertiaData::class middleware in the bootstrap/app config is not removing the middleware.
The docs says that inside the bootstrap/app config - middleware can be removed or replaced:
//...
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->web(remove: [
            \Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\ShareInertiaData::class,
        ]);
// OR
        $middleware->web(replace: [
            \Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\ShareInertiaData::class => MyCustomMiddleware::class
        ]);
}
// ALSO ON THE WEB ROUTE IS NOT WORKING
->withoutMiddleware([\Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\ShareInertiaData::class]);

The Jestream ShareInertiaData remains intact.
If an array with the same keys are placed inside the HandleInertiaRequests it overwrites the ShareInertiaData, but that means data is fetched twice before propping tthe data.
How do you remove the ShareInertiaData properly?
